# How to run multiple 'serial' processes under control considering CPUs available?

Tags: scripting, parallelism, concurrency, processes

Suppose you have a binary that has to be run on maaaaaaaaany files (suppose files are numbered from 1 to N). Each file has to be processed by making a call to this binary (say.... something like md5sum). Each run will save the result on a separate file. So.... if we have 1000 files and we only have 4 CPUs, we don't want to do something like (if at all possible, actually):

```
i=0; while [ $i -lt 1000 ]; do md5sum a_file_$i > result_$i & i=$(( $i + 1 )); done
```

Because (even if bash wouldn't complain), we would end up starting 1000 processes that will make the computer go into crawling mode.

Is there a command available that I could use where I can tell said command that it has to be run like n processes at a time (start n processes, monitors when a process finishes and then starts another so that the number of processes *running* is always n)?

Answer (score 2):

GNU [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) is the tool you're looking for.  The author, [Ole Tange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2972/ole-tange), is a regular here and has written several good answers to [questions about it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-parallel)

GNU's version of `xargs` from `findutils` also has some options for running multiple jobs in parallel.  It's probably easier to use for simple jobs like yours, but nowhere near as flexible or capable as `parallel`.

For example:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'a_file_*' -print0 | 
  xargs -0r -L 1 -P 4 sh -c '/usr/bin/md5sum "$1" > "$1.md5sum"' {}
```

This will run **up to** 4 `md5sum` jobs in parallel (`-P 4`).  I've also used `-L 1` option to limit each job to processing one filename at a time - without that (otherwise it would only run 1 job with 1000 filenames)

Comment: I ended up opening N terminal sessions on konsole and using a number sequence starting from a different index (increasing by N on each session). Not the most elegant way to handle but it worked. I'll take a look at both xargs and parallel for the next time I face something like this.